# Stripe - how do I save card element in react?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm trying to save card details for use later.

I have generated the SetupIntent client secret

I'm trying to use confirm card setup.

I'm following the docs [here](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements) for react.

The following line:

```
const cardElement = this.props.elements.getElement('card')
```

is throwing me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElement' of undefined
```

Where am I going wrong? My code is below:
This is the relevant portion of the main component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Elements, StripeProvider } from "react-stripe-elements";
import SaveCardForm from "./SaveCardForm";

<StripeProvider
apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_API_STRIPE_PUBLISH}
>

<Elements>
<SaveCardForm/>
</Elements>

</StripeProvider>
```

And this is the SaveCardForm component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Stripe, CardElement, injectStripe } from "react-stripe-elements";
import axios from "axios";


class SaveCardForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
  }


  submit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
        const cardElement = this.props.elements.getElement('card');
        axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/saveCardDetails`).then(res => {
        console.log('res.data', res.data)
        this.props.stripe.confirmCardSetup(res.data.client_secret, {
      payment_method: {
        card: cardElement,
      },
    }).then( confirmCardSetupRes => {
            console.log('confirmCardSetupRes', confirmCardSetupRes)
  })
})
}

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <CardElement />
        <button onClick={this.submit}>
          Bid For Tickets
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default injectStripe(SaveCardForm);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by updating to the latest version of react-stripe-elements.

There is an error in the versions before 5.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Given your components, there is no prop named `elements` passed into `SaveCardForm`. If it's access to `CardElement` you are after, use a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) which will give you a direct reference to that component e.g.

```
constructor(props) {
  ...
  this.cardEl = React.createRef();
}

submit = e => {
  ...     
  const card = this.cardEl.current.<accessDomHere>;
  this.props.stripe.confirmCardSetup(res.data.client_secret, {
    payment_method: {
      card
    },
  }).then(...)
}

render() {
  ...
  <div>
    <CardElement ref={this.cardEl} />
    ...
  </div>
}
```

Switch out `<accessDomHere>` for whatever DOM query you need to perform to get the information you need. There may even be a React property or function you can access (I'm not familiar with the component).